# Why attempt to index global (a nil value) Lua?

Tags: lua

Actually I'm working from a tutorial and there is some error in that tutorial.

There is the code:

```
class "Game"( Graphics )

Game.menuScreen  = nil
Game.gameScreen  = nil
Game.achScreen   = nil
Game.screen      = nil

-- main
function Game:main()
    -- Create the screens and store their links within the class
    Game.menuScreen  = MainMenu.new()
    Game.gameScreen  = GameScreen.new()
    Game.achScreen   = AchScreen.new()

    -- Display menuScreen
    Game.showScreen( 'menuScreen' )
end

-- showScreen
function Game.showScreen( name )
    -- If a screen is being displayed - remove it from the stage
    if Game.screen then
        Stage.detach( Game.screen )
        Game.screen = nil
    end

    -- Retrieve a screen link by name
    local screen = Game[name]
    if not screen then
        return nil
    end

    -- If the screen is found - add it to the stage
    Stage.attach( screen )
    -- Save the displayed screen
    Game.screen = screen

    return screen
end
```

It write to me [string "Game.script"]:11: attempt to index global 'MainMenu' (a nil value)
I use Dreemchest Composer and this one is the tutirul: http://dreemchest.com/doc/en/Game%20menu%20and%20screen.html

Actually I remowed the LEVEL select screen from this code, cos I don't want to implement a level selection to my first game in this.

I have a script named MainMenu and it's class's MainMenu, Superclass is soMainMenu.

Comment: No `nil` in `C` or `C++`. Also no `function`.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but this is not C or C++. It's [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)).

Comment: That's why i don't understood this code.. :-) I just read somewhere it's a c++ software to make games... But anyway do you know why it says to me MainMenu is nil?

Comment: Probably, you should add a line like this one: `class "MainMenu"( soMainMenu )` to create `MainMenu` prior to using it.  Undefined variables in Lua are `nil`.

Comment: The problem is that MainMenu is not declared anywhere in your file so its value is defaulting to NULL. Unfortunately, I think the solution is going to be specific to Dreemchest - from that tutorial it seems like you were supposed to declare things in separate files and that the related globals would be automatically initialized for you...

Answer (score 0):

I have got it, thank you!

I had to create Stage Objects for all menu points to get it work. It's easy but the tutorial may didn't wrote it or I just didn't understand it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on how and what you fixed. Then this would be a perfect answer.